# linking a website to a caption within shiny framework

Tags: r, shiny, href

I am trying to link a website to the word "FAQ" which is embedded in a caption. I am trying to lead users to a new webpage when users hit on FAQ.

Here is my code.

Please see "caption = ("Note: See FAQ for more information on difficulties indicators."),"

```
Diff_plot <- reactive({
ggplot(Diff_data(), aes(x =Difficulty_Type, y = Frequency_Difficulties)) + geom_bar(stat =
                                                                   "identity",
                                                                 position = "stack",
                                                                 fill = "#B61E2E") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = Percentage),
    vjust = 1,
    colour = "white", 
    position = position_dodge(width=0.9),
    fontface = "bold",
    size=5,
   # angle = 90,
    hjust = 0.5
  ) +
  labs(
    x = "",
    y = "Frequecny",



caption = ("Note: See FAQ for more information on difficulties indicators."),


    face = "bold"
  ) +
  theme_bw() + scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(
    hjust = 0.5,
    size = 15,
    colour = "Black",
    face = "bold"
  ),
  plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, color = "black", face = "bold", size=12.5),
  axis.text=(blue.bold.12.text), axis.title=blue.bold.14.text, axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -75, vjust = 0, hjust=0)) +
  ggtitle(
    paste(
      "Population by Type of Difficulty in",
      input$county_Diff,
      "for",
      input$sex_diff,
      "(", 
      input$Age_Group_Diff,
      ")"
    )
  )

  })
```

Comment: It's not possible to have the link on the word "FAQ" like with regular links, since the ggplot is rendered as an image on the page. You could have the entire PNG act as a link, so when you click on the plot it goes to the new page. You can do that in the UI script of your Shiny app.

Comment: oh sorry @Brian, didn't see your comment before I answered - do you want me to remove it?

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there any way to direct users to a new webpage when they click on FAQ.

Comment: Hi @NaderMehri do you mean to open up in a new tab? If so add `target = "_blank"` to the `a(...)` tag

Comment: Great! Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not doable I believe - `ggplot` creates an image which is then rendered in your shiny app, and the caption is part of the image rather than separate HTML surrounding it. If you run your app and inspect the source HTML you'll see the `<img>` tags where the plot is.

So your best bet is just to pretend you have a caption, and instead use a different piece of UI in your shiny app - something like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  plotOutput(outputId = "diff_plot"),
  div(tags$p("See the", a("FAQ", href = "...", target = "_blank"), "for more info"),
      style = "text-align: right;")

)

server <- function(input, output) {

  Diff_plot <- reactive({ ... })
  output$diff_plot <- renderPlot({ Diff_plot() })

}
```

Note the `target = "_blank"` necessary if you want the link to open in a new tab, rather than redirect the current page.